# PHP letters and spaces only validation

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm validating my contact form using PHP and I've used the following code:

```
if (ctype_alpha($name) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Name must only contain letters!';
}
```

This code is works fine, but it over validates and doesn't allow spaces. I've tried `ctype_alpha_s` and that comes up with a fatal error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What about hyphens and single quotes/backticks.  Those are valid characters in names as well.

Comment: and what about `John O'Reily` or `Björk Guðmundsdóttir` or `A'ishah-Yunus`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Regex is overkill and will perform worse for such a simple task, consider using native string functions:

```
if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $name)) === false) {
  $errors[] = 'Name must contain letters and spaces only';
}
```

This will strip spaces prior to running the alpha check. If tabs and new lines are an issue you could consider using this instead:

```
str_replace(array("\n", "\t", ' '), '', $name);
```

Answer (score 12):

ctype_alpha only checks for the letters  `[A-Za-z]`

If you want to use it for your purpose, first u will have to remove the spaces from your string and then apply ctype_alpha.

But I would go for preg_match to check for validation. You can do something like this.

```
if ( !preg_match ("/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/",$name)) {
   $errors[] = "Name must only contain letters!";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

One for the UTF-8 world that will match spaces and letters from any language.

```
if (!preg_match('/^[\p{L} ]+$/u', $name)){
  $errors[] = 'Name must contain letters and spaces only!';
}
```

Explanation:

- [] => character class definition
- p{L} => matches any kind of letter character from any language
- Space after the p{L} => matches spaces
- + => Quantifier — matches between one to unlimited times (greedy)
- /u => Unicode modifier. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-16. Also
  causes escape sequences to match unicode characters

This will also match names like *Björk Guðmundsdóttir* as noted in a comment by Anthony Hatzopoulos above.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $name)) === false)  {
  $errors[] = 'Name must contain letters and spaces only';
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.